# MS Word correct the style of footnotes

Tags: style, footnotes, microsoft-word

I am having an issue with a bad documents that one of my colleague formatted. The footnotes appear to have a Return too much...

[image: bad styling in a MS Word document]

I tried clicking everywhere around the area to be able to modify something, but couldn't get the | in there, so impossible to delete or remove the space after the paragraph. What I am trying to achieve is to have the bar, a return, then the 23 Random footnote text, without having this return in there.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Aie, so, contra-intuitively, I found a way to remove that little space. I am still left wondering how it landed up in there.

In any case, to solve this, or add stuffs in there, go to the **view** tab, then select **print layout** and **draft**, then in the **reference** tab, make sure the **show notes** is on, then in the dropdown list, select **footnote separator**.

I found the answer from here [source for the solution](https://excelatwork.co.nz/2013/11/02/word-how-do-i-remove-a-footnote-separator-line-in-word/)